# Catchable fatal error: Object of class Author could not be converted to string

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm learning OOP. I have a database class, Author class and a question class. What I want is to put the user input to the appropriate classes, connect to the database and insert the data from the classes.

```
    // ask.php

    $pdo = new DbConnect('host', 'dbname', 'username', 'password');

    // Create an Author object

    try {
        $author = new Author($first_name, $last_name);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    // Question object

    try {
        $question = new Question($author, $author_question);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(), '<br>';
    }

    // Insert the user input into the database

    $pdo->execute_query('INSERT INTO author (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)', array($author->getFirstName(), $author->getLastName()));
    $pdo->execute_query('INSERT INTO question (author, question) VALUES (?, ?)', array($question->getAuthor(), $question->getQuestion()));
    $pdo->close_connection();

    // class.dbconnect.php

    public function execute_query($sql, array $data = null)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

        if (!$this->stmt->execute($data)) {
            throw new Exception('Error with your query.');
        }
    }

    // class.question.php

    class Question
    {
        private $author;
        private $question;

        public function __construct(Author $author, $question)
        {
            $this->author = $author;
            $this->question = $question;
        }

        public function getAuthor()
        {
            return $this->author;
        }

        public function getQuestion()
        {
            return ucfirst($this->question);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the error? Can you post cut-down versions of your classes, too?

Comment: @i alarmed alien The error is happening inside the insert query method I created inside the class.dbconnect.php

Comment: What does `$question->getAuthor()` do? I would guess it returns an `Author` object, rather than a string.

Comment: You are right. And, I can't insert it to the database? I included the code from the question class in the post.

Comment: No--you can't put an object into a db query like that. Apart from anything, how does one represent an object as a text string?!?! PHP doesn't know, the database doesn't know, I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the classes are not shown my guess is that here:

```
    $question = new Question($author, $author_question);
```

the `Question` class constructor is using the $author a `string` which is the first parameter and you are trying to pass the whole object. You could fix that depending on your logic/inside functionality by passing an author's id/name or using that parameter as an object inside the `Question` class

** UPDATE **

Now that the classes are available, in your query you call `$question->getAuthor()` which returns an object and not the author name or id.

You could fix the `Author` class to:

```
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author->getFirstName() . " " . $this->author->getLastName()  // to return author's full name as a string!            
    }
```

or similar function so the values are and integer or string according to your logic. I would use the auto incremented ID of the Author since you are essentially trying to create relations between the two objects.

Comment: In the question constructor I specified the first parameter to accept the author object. I updated my post and included the question class.

Comment: "return $this->author->$author->getFirstName()" That $author there, is that necessary?

Comment: Nope it was a typo, and it wouldn't work that way. Fixed now but you get the idea, is that you should be getting some attributes of the object when needing to pass it as a string instead of passing the object.

Comment: Ok I accepted your answer thanks. Just curious, do you have other way of converting the object to a string? (string) would not work. How about __toString(), is that applicable in this case?

Comment: Exactly, with `__toString()` whenever trying to `echo` or cast the object as a `string`, the objects `string` representation will be returned instead of the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you're calling `$question->getAuthor`, it is returning an object, rather than a string:

```
    public function __construct(Author $author, $question)
    {
        $this->author = $author;  // this is an object
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;     // this is an object
    }
```

When you're using `$question->getAuthor()` in the database query, you need to return a string. I would suggest either you add some sort of `getAuthorName` method to Question, or that you return the author object and then call `$author->getFirstName` and `$author->getLastName` on it to get whatever format you need the author's name in.